# Как удалить первую букву или знак?

Tags: php

Даже надо 3 знака.

Answer (score 15):

**Правильный способ:** использовать [`mb_substr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)

```
$input = 'в углу скребёт мышь'; // исходная строка
$toDelete = 3; // сколько знаков надо убрать
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$result = mb_substr( $input, $toDelete); // глу скребёт мышь
```

*Неправильный* пример:

```
$input = 'в углу скребёт мышь'; // исходная строка
$toDelete = 3; // сколько знаков надо убрать
$result = substr( $input, $toDelete); // углу скребёт мышь
```

Т.к. кириллические символы — двухбайтовые, "в" занимает два байта, пробел - один. Поэтому срезалось не три символа, а лишь два.

Answer (score 2):

```
substr($text,2);  // удалит первые три символа
```

Comment: Плюсанувшие этот ответ имеют некоторое отношение к феномену г***кодерства. Подумать лень, протестировать тем более. Где-то слышали про упомянутую ф-ю, и ладно.

    $text = 'abcdef';
    echo substr($text,2) . PHP_EOL; // cdef - удалились только первые два символа

    $text = 'абвгде';
    echo substr($text,2) . PHP_EOL; // бвгде - пропал только один

Comment: Да уж, плюсов и правда много наставили, даже не пойму за что =)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$tekst = "absdefghi";
$tekst=substr($tekst,1,0);
echo $tekst;
?>
```

Comment: 0 - уберите

    $tekst = substr($tekst,1);

Или добавтье длину строки

    $tekst = substr($tekst,1, strlen($tekst));

Но лучше первый вариант

Answer (score -1):

```
$s = '12345678';
$s = preg_replace( '/^.(.*)$/', '\1', $s );
echo "$s\n"; // вывод: 2345678
$s = preg_replace( '/^./', '', $s );
echo "$s\n"; // вывод: 345678
```

Comment: @klopp, Использовать регулярку там, где для этого предусмотрена встроенная функция, на мой взгляд - не разумно.

Comment: В постановке задачи и слова не было ни о разумности, ни о целях :) А, судя по вопросу, кругозор надо ой как расширять...

Answer (score -2):

```
$matn="salom";
$matn=substr($matn,1);
echo $matn;
//выводит: alom
//или 
$matn="salom";
$matn=substr($matn,3);
echo $matn;
//выводит: om
//ещё вариант
$matn="salom";
$matn=substr($matn,-1);
echo $matn;
//выводит: salo
//или 
$matn="salom";
$matn=substr($matn,3);
echo $matn;
//выводит: sa
```

Comment: Такой ответ уже дан выше http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/135868/177188 и закритикован.